# Serialization - ReadObject error

Tags: java, serialization

I saved a drawing from my application to a file with serialization, but when i try to read that file with serialization back into the same object i get this error: `java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper`

Here you can see how my method goes:

```
public Drawing load(String nameDrawing) {
        Drawing drawing;
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(nameDrawing + ".txt")) {
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
                drawing = (Drawing) ois.readObject();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return drawing;
    }
```

I dont think that i need to make another class implements Serializable, because i managed to serialize the object into the file, so then it should be alright?

I assume it has something to do with my Drawing class and my observable list, but i dont know how to fix it. Here is a part of my drawing class:

```
public class Drawing extends DrawingItem {
    //Fields
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<DrawingItem> items;
    private Point anchor;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private ObservableList<DrawingItem> observableList;

    //Getters-setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<DrawingItem> getItems() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
    }

    public ObservableList<DrawingItem> itemsToObserve() {
        return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(observableList);
    }
```

Comment: When you **read**, you get a **write** exception? Really? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, really. When reading a serialized stream that encountered such an exception on writing, this is what happens. The curious thing here is why the OP ignored the exception when writing.

Comment: You could also use the interface Externalizable and override the methods readExternal and writeExternal with the parameters/ fields you would like to serialize. In your case everything except the observable list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have all the member of the class serializable. You can provide you own serializer or ensure types you are using are serializable + mark those that you don't need to serialize as `transient`.

Assuming DrawingItem and Point are serializable you should be fine just by doing:
`private transient ObservableList<DrawingItem> observableList;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper
```

If you read this exception, you will see that it is telling you that the class `com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper` is not `Serializable`.

It follows, as the night the day, that you have a non-transient instance member in the class you're trying to serialize that leads, in the garbage-collection sense, to a an instance of `com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper`.

Solution: find it and fix it.

The really curious thing here is why you ignored the exception when writing this stream.